# localhost refused to connect for Forge Autodesk Online Viewer

Tags: localhost, autodesk-forge

i am following the tutorial from this link: https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/overview

after i click the **Authorize me!** button, chrome shows localhost refused to connect.

there is also this message error in my cmd after runnning `npm start`:

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Jessilyn\walkthrough\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:776:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Jessilyn\walkthrough\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at C:\Users\Jessilyn\walkthrough\start.js:137:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

it loaded for the first attempt. when i tried again, this error happened. i deleted the git clone and restart the process and have been receiving the same results over and over again.

i don't understand what's going on, would appreciate if you could provide guidance.

Answer (score 0):

At which step in code you're getting the error?
Looks like the server start is not correct, do you have the proper nodejs version and all the packages installed?

Alternately you can try this similar tutorial: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels